# Count of unique values based on conditions of other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like below

```
{'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 5}, 'Color': {0: 'Blue', 1: 'Green', 2: 'Blue', 3: 'No', 4: 'Green', 5: 'No', 6: 'No', 7: 'No'}}
```

I want to distinct count IDs having Blue/Green/Blue or Green/No 
My script for Blue/Green/Blue or Green is

```
# Blue
blue = df[df['Color'] == 'Blue']
blue.Color.nunique()

# Green
green = df[df['Color'] == 'Green']
green.Color.nunique()

# Blue or Green
blue_green = df[
    (df['Color'] == 'Blue') | (df['Color'] == 'Green')
]
blue_green.Color.nunique()

# No ?
```

I do not know how to distinct count IDs not having Blue/Green at all. My expected result for No is 2 (Id 4 and 5). Any recommendations would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for something like this:

```
res = df.sort_values('Color').groupby('ID')['Color'].apply((list))\
    .value_counts()

print(res)

[No]             2
[Blue, Green]    1
[Blue, No]       1
[Green, No]      1
Name: Color, dtype: int64
```

*Explanation:*

- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to isolate `ID` groups.
- Next, use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to create lists for each `ID` and get [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).
- Note that we started with [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on the column `Color`. This avoids potentially ending up with `lists` that contain the same elements but in a different order.

You can reset the index, of course:

```
res = res.reset_index(drop=False).rename(columns={'index':'Combination',
                                                  'Color':'Count'})

print(res)

     Combination  Count
0           [No]      2
1  [Blue, Green]      1
2     [Blue, No]      1
3    [Green, No]      1
```

Comment: Big thanks @ouroboros1 for your concise script and explanation. That works perfectly well for me!